# add :onchange => "readURL(this)" to input file on simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

I have a problem with this:

I want add  `:onchange => "readURL(this)"` to my:

```
<%= f.input :image, :as => :file, :onchange => "readURL(this)" %>
```

I have tried with:

```
<%= f.input :image, :as => :file, :html => {:onchange =>
"readURL(this)"} %>
```

but I can not see the  `onchange="readURL(this)"` in html code.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you again :D.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The fix:

```
<%= f.input :image, :as => :file, :input_html => {:onchange => "readURL(this)"} %>
```

Thank you to Carlos Antonio da Silva in.

http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-simpleform/browse_thread/thread/6f2cdd83e2dbf51c